# Error while compiling Android 2.3

Tags: android, ubuntu

OS:    Ubuntu 11.04 64bit

State: While I finally reached the last step of compiling android
2.3,
   "cd ~/mydroid/android"
   "> make"
   Following is the popping up message:

```
   ====================================
   PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
   PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.3
   TARGET_PRODUCT=full_tcc8900_evm
   TARGET_GUILD_VARIANT=eng
   TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
   TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
   TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
   TARGET_ARCH=arm
   HOST_ARCH=x86
   HOST_OS=linux
   HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
   BUILD_ID=GRI 40
   ===================================
```

ERROR: After a short while, errors pop up:
     make: *** No rule to make target `dalvik/vm/compiler/template/
out/CompilerTemplateAsm-armv6-vfp.S', needed by`out/target/product/
tcc8900/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/compiler/template/
out/CompilerTemplateAsm-armv6-vfp.o'.  Stop.

QUESTION: How can I remove this error and continue building ?

Answer (score 0):

Er, I have found the way.

~/mydroid/android/dalvik/vm/compiler/template/Makefile:

TARGET_ARCH_EXT := armv6-vfp

Then '> make' under the current directory. This will generate the 'out' directory. Everything can continue.